# show currency in slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, uislider

I'm using a slider, which works fine like this:

```
{literal}
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#slider-revenue-max" ).slider({
                range: "max",
                min: 0,
                max: 10000,
                step: 100,
                value: {/literal}{if $revenue == ''}0{else}{$revenue}{/if}{literal},
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#revenue" ).val ( ui.value);
                }
            });
            $( " #revenue" ).val("£" + $( "#slider-revenue-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
        } );
    </script>
{/literal}`
```

but when moving the slider, the "£" doesn't show, so I did this:

```
{literal}
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#slider-revenue-max" ).slider({
                range: "max",
                min: 0,
                max: 10000,
                step: 100,
                value: {/literal}{if $revenue == ''}0{else}{$revenue}{/if}{literal},
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#revenue" ).val ( "£" + ui.value);
                }
            });
            $( " #revenue" ).val("£" + $( "#slider-revenue-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
        } );
    </script>
{/literal}
```

And it shows the "£" when I use this, but when I apply the filter, it shows no results.

Thanks

Comment: can you add the html of the #revenue slider? it might be possible to do a .before('$').val...

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the "£" using :before or :after via css or how I did it using Leon's noUi-slider from [refreshless.com](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) is like the below.

CSS:

```
.noUi-handle:after {
  content:attr(data-content);
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 53px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(".noUi-handle").attr("data-content", "$" + display);
```

display is just a value that is grabbed from whatever value the user has on the slider i.e. it would come up like $500 or something. Hope this helps.